# How can I find the function $f(t,x)$ from the given integral equation?

Tags: integration

$$
\int_0^\infty f(t, x)dx = \frac{2}{B+tC}
$$
given, initial condition : $f(0,x)=\frac{N_0}{x_0}\exp(-x/x_0)$

here, $N_0,x_0,B,C$  are constants

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: That integral needs a $dx$ or a $dt$ to make sense. Presumably, since you have a $t$ on the right-hand side, it's $dx$, but it would be nice if you could put it in there so we didn't have to guess.

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry about that. The Integral has dx in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is such a function only when the given equation holds for $t=0$ which means $\int_0^{\infty} \frac {N_0} {x_0} e^{-x/x_0}dx=\frac 2 B$.  In that case there are infinitely many solutions and one solution is $f(t,x)=\frac {BN_0} {x_0(B+tC)}e^{-x/x_0}$

Comment: Can you share the steps needed to reach the above solution?

Comment: When  you look for an example of such a function the first thing you should do is try to separate the variables. This means see if there is a function of the type $f(t,x)=g(t)h(x)$ . Now it is not difficult to guess what type of function $g$ and $h$ might work.